# Create if Column is Known

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working in Excel to create a Value in one column on the first time data is edited in another column in this case is is columns 3 to collect time data when column 6 is edited. I found this Code block that will trigger is a column is empty but I am new to coding and don't know how to edit this myself. Is there a way to add trigger to only do this if the column 6 has a value?

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var stampCol = sh.getRange(row, 3);

  //check if "stampCol" is empty      
  if (!stampCol.getValue()) {
const sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
sh.getRange ('C' + e.range.rowStart)
.setValue (new Date())
.setNumberFormat ('MM/dd/yyyy HH:MMam/pm');
  }
}
```

I tried searching for ways to modify those code on google and forums but find anything that helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Your sheet name" && e.range.columnStart == 6 && e.value) {
    if (e.range.offset(0, -3).getValue() === '') {
      e.range.offset(0, -3).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('MM/dd/yyyy HH:MMam/pm');
    }
  }
}
```